# Change Wait Time in Active Journey in Journey Builder Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

Need to shorten the wait time, Journey got started late so the full 1 day wait is too long, is there a way to pause, change the wait time to an hour for a particular wait step, then resume and continue the journey flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change to the wait step can only be done by creating a new journey version. Hence the changes will not apply to contacts currently in a wait step of the old version.

Comment: so technically I would have to stop the old version, make a new journey version and continue them where they left off with the new added waits (eg. email 1 already sent out, start them with email 2 in the new journey version).

Comment: Yes, @4kAudio - this is the only way